# Batch file not executing the required commands in windows 8.1

Tags: java, batch-file, jsoup

I have created a batch file to set the path of a jar file whenever i need to use that jar file.But even after executing the file,the system is unable to recognize the jar file and when i compile my java program which uses that jar file,it gives compile time error(i.e the path is not set).
And when i simply use the classpath command in command prompt which i wrote inside the batch file,it works.

But i want to make a batch file so that whenever i need to set classpath,i can use that batch file.

Help will be appreciated.

Following is the batch file.

```
set classpath=jsoup.jar;.;%classpath%
```

Comment: Are you calling javac.exe in the same process as the one where you set the classpath? 'set' isn't global... How are you calling javac.exe? Explain more, the problem is in the parts you left out of your explanation.

Comment: I am trying to first run this batch file so that the classpath of the jar file gets set and then i am compiling the program.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple ,Now am i clear to you ?

Comment: Nope. Are you running this from a cmd.exe prompt? Are you just double-clicking a .bat file icon? I need to know HOW you're running these commands.

Comment: Does your `classpath` contain a space?

Comment: @LinuxDisciple,i am double-clicking the .bat file icon.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch,No no spaces.

Comment: *i am double-clicking the .bat file icon* Then you are restarting the command session after you set the environment variables but before you run your next batch. You could (as you noted) run the environment variables script from your batch, or create a third bat to call the other two sequentially.

Comment: Environment variables are scoped to a process and its descendants. Double-clicking the batch file created a new cmd.exe process which briefly had the new classpath variable. Then that process ended, and your new classpath value went away. You need to call javac.exe from the same process using one of the methods @ElliotFrisch mentioned so your classpath value is visible by javac.exe when you run it.

Comment: Thanks,I solved the problem.I just made a .cmd file containing the command.Now whenever i will need to set the path i will run that cmd file in command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found by OP:

> Thanks,I solved the problem.I just made a .cmd file containing the command.Now whenever i will need to set the path i will run that cmd file in command prompt.